# Superl LU MT Cant get the solution X

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, suitesparse

I was trying to implement the SuperLU MT lib in my project, but i dont understand how does it work.

The Documentation says that the driver returns the solution in the Dense matrix "B" you gave through the arguments, but when i tried to print this matrix B, i get a vector of Ones.

I'm printing the B matrix in the file pzlinsol.c, from the examples.

```
pzgssv(nprocs, &A, perm_c, perm_r, &L, &U, &B, &info);
zPrint_Dense_Matrix(&B);
```

I've solve this problem with scipy, and the result isn't a vector of Ones,
I also tried a few more examples but nothing.

There has to be something that im doing wrong!

Thanks!